# Game Of Life : How to keep track of active cells

Tags: python

Now I have read the other stackoverflow Game of Life questions and also Googled voraciously.I know what to do for my Python implementation of the Game Of Life.I want to keep track of the active cells in the grid.The problem is I'm stuck at how should I code it.
Here's what I thought up but I was kinda at my wit's end beyond that:

- Maintain a ActiveCell list consisting of cell co-ordinates tuples which are active
  dead or alive.
- When computing next generation , just iterate over the ActiveCell list,compute cell
  state and check whether state changes or not.
- If state changes , add all of the present cells neighbours to the list
- If not , remove that cell from the list
- Now the problem  is : (" . "--> other cell)
         `B C D

          . A .

          . . .`
  If A satisfies 3)  then it adds B,C,D
  then if B also returns true for 3) ,which means it will add A,C again
  (Duplication)

I considered using OrderedSet or something to take care of the order and avoid duplication.But still these I hit these issues.I just need a direction.

Comment: Have you considered a numpy array? You could then use a mask to set the update rules of the CA. Tasks like that are always easier (and faster) with numpy.

Comment: Added an answer with sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two lists, I'll name them currentState, and newChanges.  Here will be the workflow:

1. Iterate over currentState, figuring out which are newly born cells, and which ones are going to die.  **Do NOT add these changes to your currentState**.  If there is a cell to be born or a death, add it to the newChanges list.  When you are finished with this step, currentState should look exactly the same as it did at the beginning.
2. Once you have finished all calculations in step 1 for *every* cell, then iterate over newChanges.  For each pair in newChanges, change it in currentState from dead to alive or vice versa.

Example:

- currentState has {0,0} {0,1} {0,2}. (Three dots in a line)
- newChanges is calculated to be {0,0} {-1,1} {1,1} {0,2} (The two end dots die, and the spot above and below the middle are born)
- currentState recieves the changes, and becomes {-1,1} {0,1} {1 ,1}, and newChanges is cleared.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your suggestion? If I have a Set representing all the cells which have changed, then what's the purpose of ActiveCell ?

Comment: Basically the Set keeps track of all of the changes that are going to be made, while the ActiveCell list keeps track of the current state.  Because all of your calculations have to be done on the current state, (which shouldn't change as your calculate), you have to store your changes somewhere else while you are still calculating. Once you are done calculating all of the changes, then you can apply them

Comment: OK, but I don't think it still tackles the aforementioned problem.Suppose a cell A is a neighbour of B.Let both of them be in active set(last generation) and currently B has not changed but A has.If I check B first then its alright.However,check it vice versa.If A is checked first,it will add B with it to the set.Check B,not changed so remove it.Meaning B will not be in the set only.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding your last comment.  Maybe renaming the sets would make more sense.  I've edited my answer with a more descriptive flow

Comment: "for _every_ cell " means every cell in the grid right? then for coming generations I just need to iterate over the currentState list to process the cells which _have_ changed in the generation before that ?

Comment: Correct.  I've added an example for added clarity.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I fail to see how this solves the problem. In your example above, how do you do this part: "newChanges is calculated to be {0,0} {-1,1} {1,1} {0,2} ", without having duplicate values in this list?

Comment: @Bob I'm not sure I understand.  You take all of the points in current, and iterate through adjacent points, and for each of those points, calculate their neighbors.  (Furthermore, even if your algorithm does have duplicate values, you can just assign them to a set, which removes duplicates)

Comment: oh so you're using a set. Can you do this without a set? Don't want to hash and check

Comment: @Bob The set is going to be the most efficient way.  If you didn't want to do that, you'd need to find the smallest rectangle around all of the points, and iterate through that rectangle.  (This could be optimizing by allowing multiple, non-overlapping rectangles)

Comment: @NathanMerrill how about a second array which acts as a flag? So before adding a neighbour to the list, check if the flag in the array for that neighbour has been set yet. Im doing this in C so we dont have sets

Comment: That would work.  I highly recommend finding a library for sets as they are incredibly useful and efficient.

Answer (score 3):

don't know if it will help you, but here's a quick sketch of Game of Life, with activecells dictionary:

```
from itertools import product

def show(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

def init(N):
    board = []
    for x in range(N):
        board.append([])
        for y in range(N):
            board[x].append(".");
    return board

def create_plane(board):
    board[2][0] = "x"
    board[2][1] = "x"
    board[2][2] = "x"
    board[1][2] = "x"
    board[0][1] = "x"

def neighbors(i, j, N):
    g1 = {x for x in product([1, 0, -1], repeat=2) if x != (0, 0)}
    g2 = {(i + di, j + dj) for di, dj in g1}
    return [(x, y) for x, y in g2 if x >= 0 and x < N and y >= 0 and y < N]

def live(board):
    N = len(board)
    acells = {}
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if board[i][j] == "x":
                for (x, y) in neighbors(i, j, N):
                    if (x, y) not in acells: acells[(x, y)] = board[x][y]

    while True:
        print "-" * 2 * N, len(acells), "cells to check"
        show(board)
        raw_input("Press any key...")
        for c in acells.keys():
            a = len([x for x in neighbors(c[0], c[1], N) if board[x[0]][x[1]] == "x"])
            cur = board[c[0]][c[1]]
            if a == 0:
                del acells[c]                       # if no live cells around, remove from active
            elif cur == "x" and a not in (2, 3):
                acells[c] = "."                     # if alive and not 2 or 3 neighbors - dead
            elif cur == "." and a == 3:
                acells[c] = "x"                     # if dead and 3 neighbors - alive
                for x in neighbors(c[0], c[1], N):  # add all neighbors of new born
                    if x not in acells: acells[x] = board[x[0]][x[1]] 

        for c in acells:
            board[c[0]][c[1]] = acells[c]

N = 7
board = init(N)
create_plane(board)

live(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using an ordered dictionary and just set the values to None?

Comment: So the keys of your dictionary will be the active cells and what would the values be? I don't understand

Comment: The values would be null(None), just a placeholder. http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state that you have a restriction to implement the game in a specific way.  So, the main question is: how big a grid do you want to be able to handle?

For example, if you are starting with a small fixed-size grid, the simplest representation is just a [[bool]] or [[int]] containing whether each cell is alive or dead.  So, each round, you can make a new grid from the old one, e.g. assuming that all cells outside the grid are dead.  Example:

```
[
  [False, True, False],
  [True, False, True],
  [False, True, False],
]
```

If you want a very large dynamic-sized grid, there's the [HashLife algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashlife), which is much faster, but more complicated.

Comment: The size of the grid is irrelevant.Your asking if its static or dynamic.Static it is .Yes, HashLife is fast but complicated and bit overkill right now.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Game of Life in Python for fun and what I did was having board dict, with tuples of coordinates. Value is a state of cell. You can look at the code here https://raw.github.com/tdi/pycello/master/pycello.py. I know this is not very fast implementation and the project is abandoned due to lack of time.

```
 board = {}
 board[(x,y)] = value
```